# 1 Publisher Class Event, Multiple Subscribers, Different Parameters

Tags: c#, events, delegates, eventargs

I am using delegates and events to pass data around in my application, but want the triggering of 1 event to pass different sets of data to different places.

**Problem**

I have a main class which performs some work.  Once the work is complete, I want it to notify a number of other classes (including the UI) so that other actions can be carried out.  The information that the other classes needs is different.

**Example**

Main.cs - Performs an action and wants to update the UI, send a text message and write to a log file.

UI updates a DataGrid so needs the individual fields.

The log file writer needs all the whole line as an array / List.

The text message code needs the Line, LineNumber and FileName, but as a tab delimited string.

The below all works correctly when I am only trying to update the UI, but when I try to send different information to different places then I run into errors.

I have tried creating different extensions of EventArgs, but if I try to declare 2 delegates with different signatures then I get an error message.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**FrmMain.cs**

```
Main main = new Main();
main.PatternFound += OnPatternFound;

main.DoSomeWork();

private void OnPatternFound(object source, LineEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateDataGrid(e.Line, e.FileName, e.LineNumber);
    }

private void UpdateDataGrid(string line, string file, int lineNumber)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action<string, string, int>(UpdateDataGrid), line, file, lineNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            dgResults.Rows.Add(line, file, lineNumber);
        }            
    }
```

**Main.cs**

```
public delegate void PatternFoundEventHandler(object sender, LineEventArgs e);
public event PatternFoundEventHandler PatternFound;

protected virtual void OnPatternFound(string line, string fileName, int lineNumber)
    {
        PatternFound?.Invoke(this, new LineEventArgs { Line = line, FileName = fileName, LineNumber = lineNumber });
    }

public void DoSomeWork()
{
    //Finished my work
    OnPatternFound(line, file, lineNumber);
}
```

**LineEventArgs.cs**

```
public class LineEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"information that the other classes needs is different"* - you will have to decide what to put in `EventArgs` to satisfy majority of the needs. Or just add **multiple events**. I personally like another approach, where `sender` is used as a way to access all as instance members (`EventArgs` is not used). Be careful with multithreading though.

Comment: Thanks Sinatr.  So with the way that you do it, in the subscribers you would take the source and know that the caller was Main.  From there you would access Main.Line, Main.LineNumber, Main.FileName directly as they are public properties?

Comment: Yes. Though as I said, be careful. `InvokeRequired` tells you might have multithreading. Access to public members may require some kind of acquisition pattern. E.g. something bad may happen if you read public property with value of *previous* event. That's where `EventArgs` are safe, once instance is created it will persist (typically immutable) for all event handlers for a given event. Next event - new `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is possibly not a good approach for several reasons. Your decided to stick to events which means you decided to do what is called "inversion of control".

You implemented your main class in a way that says: "I am doing some sort of pattern matching and I will tell whoever is interested what I found and I am doing it in the way my event-args implementation defines." As a result it's now up to the subscribers to take this information as is or leave it.

Strictly spoken, what you said...

> Performs an action and wants to update the UI, send a text message and write to a log file.

...is not what you implemented, because the main class does nothing of this. Anyway, in my opinion it is a viable solution to keep it event-driven, but then you would need to change your upstream code.

You could for example attach three different event handlers to this single event. Every handler would then have to transform the data in a format it needs: The logging handler would have to transform it to an array, the UI handler would have to concatenate it and so on.

The other alternative would be that you have one handler and dispatch to three different methods, like the `OnPatternFound` method would call a `UpdateUI` method and a `Log` method and so on.

Lastly you could also get rid of inversion of control and move your logic to the main class, but I would **not recommend it**! Your approach is good, but you should just not try to invoke the same event in three different ways. That's up to the subscribers.

Comment: Thanks Peit.  So if I try to keep the code as clean as possible, if I were to implement your suggestion of, "The other alternative would be that you have one handler and dispatch to three different methods", to avoid breaking DIP I would have to create some sort of Interface and pass an instance of the LogWriter, TextMessageSender, etc to the constructor of the Main class?  If not is there another way to achieve this without tightly coupling my code?

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. Of course you have many different opportunities. What I had on my mind was just what you wrote, except that your method ``OnPatternFound`` dispatches to three meaningful other methods: ``private void OnPatternFound(object source, LineEventArgs e) { UpdateDataGrid(e.Line, e.FileName, e.LineNumber); WriteLogMessage(...); SendTextMessage(...); }``.

Comment: Got it.  I see what you mean now.  Thanks.